# Angular Universal, Server Side Rendering, and Observing Outgoing HTTP requests in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular-universal

I'm using Angular Universal and trying to figure out a way to intercept outgoing HTTP requests for a small caching layer. Because the HTTP requests are done inside `@nguniversal`, I can't wrap `request`.

psuedo code would ideally look something like this:

```
server.on('request', function (req, res) {
   if (cache[req.url]) res.end(cache[req.url]);
   req.continue();
});
```

To be clear, **I am not looking to cache the state**. I'm looking to cache communication between the frontend server and API server.

```
Client <------> Frontend Server (Angular Universal) <-------> API Server
                                                        ^ 
                                          How to cache this?
```

Comment: Are these http requests from the @angular/http module?

Comment: Yes, but the app is bootstrapped on all page requests. The goal here is to cache expensive API endpoints on the frontend SERVER. Anything inside @angular's modules or application isn't going to be helpful, as those are regenerated at every page request.

Comment: Would [TransferState](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c) help here?

Comment: No. TransferState is for transferring the server from the client. I want to cache the initial server-to-server requests.

Comment: Gotcha. Misunderstood.

Comment: @MattEnth did you solve your issue somehow? Thanks!